# GGplot2 - error 'mapping' must be created by 'aes()'

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, aes, ggpubr

I am new to R and have a little problem with ggplot. Here's part of the data:

```
    dput(base_df[1:5, -c(1,4:18)])
base_df <- structure(list(pre_exposure = structure(c(8L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("All seronegative", 
"B seropositive only", "H3 seropositive only", "H1 seropositive only", 
"H3 and B seropositive", "H1 and H3 seropositive", "H1 and B seropositive", 
"All seropositive"), class = "factor"), of_v0_total_iga_elisa = c(14.43528799, 
4.918994451, 27.68948908, 28.98430055, 35.08496692), ph1n1_cali_09_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 
123.70414442657, 11.1414117865695, 8.69436195519992, 69.0324150945501
), ph1n1_mich_15_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 52.0431568992636, 2.74472381127807, 
1.50081248036189, 74.6473555460887), h2n2_cana_05_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 
4.57410558684934, 3.28644561613558, 1.17304883522539, 4.58885996293252
), h5n8_duck_16_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 11.1811469900762, 2.94335513972582, 
1.43180960770157, 4.36084207657563), h5n8_turk_14_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 
6.40374782158908, 1.46264887311529, 0.983290935409514, 2.1519188024932
), h9n2_guin_14_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 17.2799544392086, 5.61584937702289, 
3.98491589613329, 3.52002612063458), h3n2_bris_07_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 
133.868823508457, 103.071602070889, 25.0997949301902, 11.828427854764
), h3n2_hong_14_ha1_cell_adjusted = c(NA, 189.266324504744, 314.451450326291, 
101.192712756355, 31.3809616098678), h3n2_hong_14_ha1_egg_adjusted = c(NA, 
42.5900053531083, 24.9553178104361, 9.97091509941578, 8.97820427530276
), h7n7_chic_03_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 5.18398633176259, 1.17373057719128, 
0.155256463485713, 0.655551423276075), b_texa_13_ha1_adjusted = c(NA, 
6.7086881940457, 3.06975689419257, 9.17738206382213, 5.05914685354362
), ph1n1_mich_15_na_adjusted = c(NA, 16.161839740201, 8.10776967936745, 
3.77790727815234, 6.56976535065805), ph1n1_cali_09_na_adjusted = c(NA, 
12.095968107446, 7.27712957858593, 4.24367666860948, 6.62676982224728
), h3n2_hong_14_na_adjusted = c(NA, 27.6479271027338, 11.8637075263795, 
9.67765289060943, 4.5318554913433), b_texa_13_na_adjusted = c(NA, 
16.7717204851142, 255.855208434203, 4.95095611337773, 64.6288196642826
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
```

This is the code I ran:

```
antigens <- c("ph1n1_cali_09_ha1", "ph1n1_mich_15_ha1", "h2n2_cana_05_ha1", "h5n8_duck_16_ha1",
          "h5n8_turk_14_ha1", "h9n2_guin_14_ha1", "h3n2_bris_07_ha1", "h3n2_hong_14_ha1_cell",
          "h3n2_hong_14_ha1_egg", "h7n7_chic_03_ha1", "b_texa_13_ha1", "ph1n1_mich_15_na",
          "ph1n1_cali_09_na", "h3n2_hong_14_na", "b_texa_13_na")

for(antigen in antigens) {

ggplot(base_df, aes(x=pre_exposure, y=log10(eval(as.symbol(paste0(antigen, "_adjusted")))))) + 
geom_boxplot(width=0.3, na.rm = TRUE) +
geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.1), na.rm = TRUE) + 
stat_summary(fun=median, geom="crossbar", color="red", width = 0.3, na.rm = TRUE) + 
stat_compare_means(paste0(antigen, "_adjusted")~pre_exposure, method="kruskal.test") +
theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle(paste0(antigen, " specific IgA by influenza pre-exposure") ) + 
ylab("Log10 florescence / total IgA") +
xlab("Pre-exposure status") +
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("All seronegative","H1 seropositive only", "H3 seropositive only", 
                          "B seropositive only", "H1 and H3 seropositive", "H1 and B seropositive",
                          "H3 and B seropositive", "All seropositive"))

 ggsave(paste0(antigen, ".svg")) }
```

If I run the ggplot loop without the line `stat_compare_means(paste0(antigen, "_adjusted")~pre_exposure, method="kruskal.test")` R runs my code and there doesn't seem to be any problem. But once I add the `stat_compare_means` to add p-values to my plots, the error

> 'mapping' must be created by 'aes()'

pops up. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please can you share some data so that others can reproduce your problem. Use `dput(base_df)` to make it easy to import. Do you really want each plot in a separate file - might be better to use facets

Comment: If you don't produce a reproducible code, I can't help you out because I can't run your code. However, try to change that line with `stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0(antigen, "_adjusted")~pre_exposure), method="kruskal.test") +`. Though, I'm not really sure what you want to do with `~pre_exposure`

Comment: Like most (all?) commands that generate `ggproto` objects, the first argument for `stat_compare_means()` is `mapping=`.  That means your `paste0(...)` part is directly set to `mapping=`, which will give the error you see.  You need to have `mapping=aes()`, and then associate the `paste0(...)` command with some aesthetic, which seems to be `label=` in your case.    Follow @Edo's note above and that should fix your error.

Comment: @RichardTelford you should be able to run this now, I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Edo I updated the code, you should be able to run it now. With antigen, "_adjusted"~pre_exposure I want to run a kruskal-wallis test if that makes sense

Comment: actually I think it will work even without that formula. You are already specifying X and Y in the ggplot. `stat_compare_means(method="kruskal.test") +`

Comment: Removing the formula as @Edo suggests will fix your error, but expose another. ggpubr does not seem to play nicely with the `scale_x_discrete`. Remove that as well and the code should work. If you want to change the order of the labels, better to change the order of the levels in pre_exposure

Comment: @RichardTelford Many many thanks! It finally worked! Will keep that in mind next time I'll use ggplot2 and ggpubr!